# what property/field is used when querying in weaviate

Tags: weaviate

When we run queries on weaviate, what property the query is running on? Or is it running on all properties of each entry?
Look at the following example, `nearText` is running on all three properties `"question", "answer", "category"` here? If that is the case, is there a way to specify a specific property to run the query on? For example, if I want to run `nearText` just on `question`, is there such a way?

```
import weaviate
import json

client = weaviate.Client(
    url="https://some-endpoint.weaviate.network/",  # Replace with your endpoint
    additional_headers={
        "X-OpenAI-Api-Key": "<THE-KEY>"  # Replace with your API key
    }
)

nearText = {"concepts": ["biology"]}

result = (
    client.query
    .get("Question", ["question", "answer", "category"])
    .with_near_text(nearText)
    .with_limit(2)
    .do()
)

print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `with_near_text()` is a pure vector search, translating the query into a vector embedding.

Weaviate knows what to vectorize based on your schema.

Take the following schema:

```
{
    "classes": [
        {
            "class": "Publication",
            "description": "A publication with an online source",
            "moduleConfig": {
                "text2vec-transformers": {
                    "poolingStrategy": "masked_mean",
                    "vectorizeClassName": false
                }
            },
            "properties": [
                {
                    "dataType": [
                        "string"
                    ],
                    "description": "Name of the publication",
                    "moduleConfig": {
                        "text2vec-transformers": {
                            "skip": false,
                            "vectorizePropertyName": false
                        }
                    },
                    "name": "name",
                    "tokenization": "word"
                }
            ],
            "vectorizer": "text2vec-transformers"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note the `"text2vec-transformers": { "skip": false, "vectorizePropertyName": false }` section.

This says that it will *not* skip (because `skip: false` the property when creating a vector).

In other words, the vector is based on the property `name`.

It's explained in a bit more detail here: https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/tutorials/schema#class-property-specification-examples